# how to use order by multiple times on the results set along with rownum (oracle)

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, rownum

I have the below tables:

```
person table 
personid |   firstname | lastname
------------------------------
P1       |  Jim        |  John
P2       |  Kori       |  Test
P3       |    Adam     |    Blair
P4       |    Kim      |    sand
P5       |    julia    |   Dan

order table 
orderno |ordername | price | personid
---------------------------------
1       |shoes     |  100  | P1
2       |books     |  50   |P2
3       | pen      |   10  |P3
4       |laptop    |  80   |P4
5       |notebook  |   40  |P5

Email address table
clientid    emailid
---------------------
P1      |   jom.John@test.com
P3      |     adam.blair@test.com
P4      |    kim.sand@test.com
```

I have to get the top 3 person names ordered by 'price' and then get rid of the persons who dont have an email address and this final list  should be ordered by firstname (desc) 
My results should look like:

```
Firstname   lastname  price
------------------------------
Kim       |   sand   |  80
Jim       |  john    | 100

I tried minus but not able to figure out how to use order by (first by price) and then for the final results by firstname. oracle is not liking the combination of multiple order by and rownum together.
Any pointers would be helpful.
```

Comment: What if one person has many orders ? Do you want to sort by sum of all prices belonging to this person, or only one price ( the highest, the lowest etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT P.FIRSTNAME,P.LASTNAME,O.PRICE FROM PERSON_TABLE P
INNER JOIN ORDER_TABLE O
ON P.PERSONID = O.PERSONID
AND P.PERSONID NOT IN 
       (SELECT E.CLIENTID FROM EMAIL_ADDRESS_TABLE E)
ORDER BY P.FIRSTNAME desc;
```

output:

```
Firstname lastname price
------------------------
kim       | sand   | 80 
julia     | dan    | 40
```

My result is not look like as your but it may be help you. I wrote above script as per your above mentioned requirement.